# Smooth maps of kahler manifold

Tags: vector-fields, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M,g ,J , \omega)$ be a Kahler manifold.
Prove that the following two statements are equivalent foe very smooth functions $f :M  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

1. the Hamiltonian vector field $X := df$ preserves metric $g$ i.e
   $$ L_X g=0$$ 
   where $L_X$ is lie derivative along $X$;
2. denoting by $D$ and $\overline{D}$  the holomorphic and antiholomorphic part of covariant derivative induce by $g$, we have
   $$ DDf=0 \quad \quad \overline{D}~ \overline{D}f=0 $$.

Comment: What have you tried? Vector fields that preserve the metric are called Killing fields. For a Killing vector field $X$, we have that $\nabla X$ is skew-adjoint.